# Unity: Input.GetButtonDown is not reliably detected in Update?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player script that I'm trying to implement jumping in. The problem is that `Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")` doesn't consistently fire in Update. I know this is a problem when it's in FixedUpdate. Here is my code.

Note: I put `[SerializeField]` on `pressingJump` and `holdingJump` so I could see what's happening. `pressingJump` is inconsistent (as expected) but `holdingJump` works perfectly.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fallMultiplier = 15f;
    public float lowJumpMultiplier = 10f;
    public float walkSpeed = 20f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 15f;

    public bool canMove = true;
    public bool canJump = true;
    
    Rigidbody rb;

    float horizontalInput;
    bool doJump;
    bool pressingJump;
    bool holdingJump;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CaputureInput();
    }

    void CaputureInput()
    {
        if (canMove) {
            horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        }
        

        pressingJump = Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump");
        doJump = pressingJump && canJump;
        holdingJump = Input.GetButton ("Jump") && canJump;
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        Jump();
    }
    
    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * walkSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    
    void Jump()
    {
        if (doJump) {
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * jumpSpeed;
            doJump = false;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0) {
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * Physics.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && !holdingJump) {
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * Physics.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok found the solution here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/9nr2sd/inputgetbuttondown_and_getbuttonup_dont_work/e7ogta1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

This was the problem I was having.

**Edit**: Comment pointed out a link might not be accepted. Here is the relevant content from link. It points out why the issue is occurring and how to fix it.

> What you end up with, with the code you've written, is essentially the
> same as when you do input checking in FixedUpdate.
>
> This is because Update runs several times in between every
> FixedUpdate. Now, what this means for your code in this case is that
> yes, you do capture the state of ButtonDown("Jump") during Update, but
> think about this: what happens to button_down/up_jump if another
> Update happens before a FixedUpdate? Both GetButtonDown and
> GetButtonUp are functions that are true only for the one frame in
> which the keypress/-release happened. In other words, this is
> happening
>
> Update runs -> button_down_jump is false
>
> user presses "Jump".
>
> Update runs -> button_down_jump is true
>
> Update runs -> button_down_jump is false
>
> FixedUpdate runs -> nothing happens, because of button_down_jump's
> state
>
> Now, you've actually had a few cases where you press/unpress "jump" at
> just the right time to manage to get anything printed at all. This
> will only happen given that the following happens:
>
> User un-/press "jump"
>
> Update runs (ONCE)
>
> FixedUpdate runs
>
> What you actually want to do is something like this:
>
> void Update() {
> if(Input.GetButtonDown("jump")) {
> button_down_jump = true; //this captures the state of the boolean beyond the one frame, as it's only set whenever the input
> event happens
> }
> if(Input.GetButtonUp("jump")) {
> button_up_jump = true;
> } }

Comment: Links are generally not accepted as answers because they could be deleted and therefore made inaccessible for others with the same problem